# Python: Phantomjs cannot find element where chrome webdriver works fine

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to download a CSV from a webpage. The download starts as I click on a image in the page. When I try to do so with `ChromeWebDriver` everything works fine, but I need to use `PhantomJS`, and for some reason it is not able to find the element.
Looking it up, I have seen that sometime it is enough changing the way it finds the element, unfortunately the text, `img` and class to access this element are `reapeated` several times in the page.
Can someone help me out?
Here is what I have coded:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
    
PATH='vvv' 
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : 'vvv'}
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(PATH,desired_capabilities=prefs)
driver.get('https://infostat-ivass.bancaditalia.it/RIGAInquiry-public/ng/#/area-download')
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/inquiry-root/div/inquiry-area-download/div[2]/inquiry-grid/ag-grid-angular/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/inquiry-pdf-csv/div/img")
target.click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ffff.py", line 18, in <module>
    target = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/inquiry-root/div/inquiry-area-download/div[2]/inquiry-grid/ag-grid-angular/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/inquiry-pdf-csv/div/img")
  File "fff\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "ffff\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "ffff\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "fffff\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '/html/body/inquiry-root/div/inquiry-area-download/div[2]/inquiry-grid/ag-grid-angular/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/inquiry-pdf-csv/div/img'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Content-Length":"244","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:62209","User-Agent":"selenium/3.141.0 (python windows)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"value\": \"/html/body/inquiry-root/div/inquiry-area-download/div[2]/inquiry-grid/ag-grid-angular/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/inquiry-pdf-csv/div/img\", \"sessionId\": \"9dbc06c0-113f-11ec-a5dd-dfc6f1996a7b\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/9dbc06c0-113f-11ec-a5dd-dfc6f1996a7b/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the exact issue is, but your `xpath` looks `brittle`.

try this **instead** :

```
//div[contains(text(),'Lista eventi')]//following-sibling::div[4]//descendant::div
```

also for any specific `Descrizione`, you would have to make changes here, `contains(text(),'Lista eventi')`